# how do I link github and Rstudio when I see Untracked files?

Tags: r, git, github

I am new in github. I want to use version control and create GitHub repository and clone one in my Rstudio, so I did following steps in terminal ( MAC): 
1. *pwd*
*/Users/wulingqi*

2. *cd ~/Documents/R/temporary*
3. git commit -m "initial commit"
   Now, I can not create new file but get this: 
   *On branch master
   Initial commit
   Untracked files:
   .Rhistory
   .Rproj.user/
   nothing added to commit but untracked files present*
4. And then I paste code from GitHub website, paste and refresh, but no change in the website: 
   *git remote add origin https://github.com/lingqi-w/temporary.git
   git push -u origin master*

Could someone give me some advice on this? Thank you.

Comment: As for step 4: I got following errors:error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/lingqi-w/temporary.git'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the terminal, you need to stage the files you want to commit. This holds for both untracked and modified files. You can stage files by using:

```
git add [path_to_file]
```

Use `git add .` to add all files in your current directory and its subdirectories or use `git add src/file*` to add all files that have a path that start with src/file*

After that you have staged the files you want to commit, you can retry to use:

```
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

If you then want to push to github you can use:

```
git push origin master
```